# How to combine queries using Access sql

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have a table like below and i'm trying to select 1 series EID's i.e 1001,1002,1003,1004,1005 and 2 series EID's as seperate queries

```
     EID     PCNum

     1001     8.6
     1002     10
     1003     9
     1004     8
     1005     7
     2001     4
     2002     1
     2003     2
     2004     3
     2005     6  
     3001     8
     3002     0
     3003     7
     3004     4
     3005     4
```

And queries combined like below

```
     EID     PCNum   EID     PCNum    EID     PCNum

     1001     8.6    2001     4       3001     8
     1002     10     2002     1       3002     8
     1003     9      2003     2       3003     8
     1004     8      2004     3       3004     8
     1005     7      2005     6       3005     8
```

How do i specify that in a sql query? Any suggestions? I tried UNION but giving some errors.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you would have a column which would separate out EID from series, leaving you with just values like 001, 002, etc.

In this case you could `JOIN` the data on itself +1000 times the series number. Something like this:

```
SELECT 
    t1.EID, t1.PCNum,
    t2.EID, t2.PCNum,
    t3.EID, t3.PCNum
FROM 
    table_name t1
    INNER JOIN table_name t2 on t1.EID+1000 = t2.EID
    INNER JOIN table_name t3 on t1.EID+2000 = t3.EID
WHERE t1.EID BETWEEN 1000 AND 1999
ORDER BY t1.EID
```